# Select different JSON according to user choice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, web

I'm currently building my first AngularJS website. The goal is simple, I have multiple JSON files containing different data (but the files have the same "skeleton") and I want to display the data according to the user choice.

Ex: the user chooses "ice cream" the page would display all the ice creams flavors.

For now I'm only loading one json file:

```
    angular.module('webBIFStatistics', []).controller('statsController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('../app/sources/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.variables = data;
  });
});
```

How may I simply handle several json files to be loaded in AngularJS?

Note that I may have to load 150+ different files.

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like this. The data binding for the view would either need to have the same keypair names or a direct lookup based on position. e.g. data[key].itemName or data[key][1]

```
 angular.module('webBIFStatistics', []).controller('statsController', function($scope, $http, target) {
  var finalTarget = '../app/sources/'+ target;
  $http.get(finalTarget).success(function(data) {
    $scope.variables = data;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable that will be selected by the user, and make your API call with this variable:

```
$scope.userChoice = 'iceCreams.json';

$http.get('../app/sources/' + userChoice).success(function(data) {
    $scope.variables = data;
});
```